# How to download csv file and zip file in python?

Tags: python

I have been trying to download the csv and zip file from the given links:

** https://nseindia.com/content/fo/fo.zip
** https://nseindia.com/archives/nsccl/sett/FOSett_prce_17052019.csv

The following code gives an error as  HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

```python
import urllib.request

csv_url = 'https://nseindia.com/archives/nsccl/sett/FOSett_prce_17052019.csv'

urllib.request.urlretrieve(csv_url, '17_05.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem of yours is because the default User-Agent (`Python-urllib/3.7`) of Python-urllib is blocked by the website server. However, you can bypass the blockage by changing the User-Agent header:

```python
import urllib.request
opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

csv_url = 'https://nseindia.com/archives/nsccl/sett/FOSett_prce_17052019.csv'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(csv_url, '17_05.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can get the content of the CSV file and you can write the CSV file.

```
import csv
import requests

CSV_URL = 'https://nseindia.com/archives/nsccl/sett/FOSett_prce_17052019.csv'


with requests.Session() as s:
    download = s.get(CSV_URL)

    decoded_content = download.content.decode('utf-8')

    cr = csv.reader(decoded_content.splitlines(), delimiter=',')
    my_list = list(cr)
    for row in my_list:
        print(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the package `requests`.

```
pip install requests
```

Then, use `requests.get` api to download the file and then write it to the desired file.

```
import requests

csv_url = 'https://nseindia.com/archives/nsccl/sett/FOSett_prce_17052019.csv'

r = requests.get(csv_url, allow_redirects=True)

open('test.csv', 'wb').write(r.content)
```